# Scala - error: recursive variable name needs type

Tags: scala

I'm using an older version of scala `2.7.5`

When i try to do computations like this,

`var x = 100`

`var x = x%1000`

I get a

`error: recursive variable x needs type`

Is there a work around? why do i get this error?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve there? you're declaring a new variable and initializing it with reference to itself? if shouldn't allow you to do that

Comment: @KimStebel please see edit

Comment: For me, in addition to the error you show, it also gives the error "x  is already defined as variable x"

Answer (score 12):

You're declaring the variable twice rather than just changing its value. Instead, do

```
var x = 100
x = x%1000
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering, in this particular case Kim Stebel already wrote the correct solution.
If you just wanted to solve the type error for `var x = x%1000` the solution would be simple like this: `var x:Int = x%1000` (which equals to 0, because of the default int value of the JVM, this is a really weird recursive expression though)